# Scala, collections, variable access scope

Tags: scala, collections

Sorry, I got even no idea how to name a title, as I believe this is a dead simple thing.

I have function which is taking Int as an argument and returning List of Ints (after adding values to int trough loop, and couple if statements. Signature is a must)

My problem:

```
def a(i:Int) = { var l2 = List(1,2); l2.+:(1); l2; }
println(a(3)) // outputs List(1, 2)
```

Why function a is returning `List(1,2)` instead of `List(3,1,2)`  ??
And what would be a correct solution in this situation?
I really appreciate your time to help me.

Comment: Please use markup when posting on SO and remove the unnecessary stuff from your code, so it can be copy pasted as is

Answer (score 1):

The method `+:` that you are calling on a `List` returns a new list with the element prepended. The original list is not modified.

In the statement `l2.+:(1)` you are ignoring the return value (the new list with the element prepended). Then you return `l2`, which still refers to the original `List` which contains the two elements `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an assignment (and you probably meant `i` instead of `1`): `l2 +:= i`.

But in scala it is preferable to avoid using `var`:

```
def a(i: Int) = { i :: List(1, 2) }
```

(I guess your method is much more complex, but it's almost always possible to rewrite it that way)